# is there any proper solution to get and save the hindi characters also to show these characters to jsp page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, utf-8

---

My operation is to save the hindi character in db and fetch the same at another place.
for start i was trying this :-

```
byte[] ob=null;
    String obj="";

    String original11=new String("".getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));  
     original11 = "गुणवत्ता"; 
    try {


        System.out.println(original11);
        System.out.println(new String(original11.getBytes()));




              System.out.println(new String(original11.getBytes("windows-1252"), "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println(new String(original11.getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    byte[] bytearr = original11.getBytes("UTF-8");

     obj = new String(bytearr,Charset.defaultCharset());




    System.out.println("obj "+obj);

    ob=Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytearr);

    String encStr = new String(ob);


    System.out.println(encStr);


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when i am trying to set this normally(without getting connect with database),at the first sout i am getting questions marks(????????).
and in the second sout i am getting the same and the getBytes() is returning [63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics.

- `String/Reader/Writer` keeps Unicode text, so all scripts are possible.
- `byte[]/InputStream/OutputStream` is for binary data. If actually text, one needs to know their charset/encoding. `UTF_8` is one of the Unicode charsets, allowing international text in bytes. This charset is for converting the bytes to or from String.
- Hard coded strings must be compiled with the same charset as the editor. Assumed is that the editor's charset can represent the string. To check that one may compare it with u-escaped characters: `"\uXXXX\uXXXX"`.
- Avoid `new String(bytes)` and `string.getBytes()` which use the default platform charset, which is not portable.

  ```
  String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  ```

The other forms one should forget, and *never* `new String(s.getBytes...)`.

- The database table and table column should be Unicode capable. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139568/31066) from Solomon Rutzky. Note that using NVARCHAR using UCS-2 (almost UTF-16) might require 2 NVARCHARs for one Unicode symbol. Keep the reserved length large enough.
- JSPs can indicate their pageEncoding. Forms can mention with the accept-charset that UTF-8 is accepted. `URLEncoder` can encode parameters in UTF-8 as %..%..%.. .